# Every finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field

> I want to know if every finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra or not.

Although by Artin-Tate lemma we can see that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra which is not finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra since $\mathbb{C}$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}.$

I want to know is this  true in general ? And also want to know what happens if $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}.$ Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-zero $\mathbb C$-algebra is not denumerable  and thus **never** a finitely generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra.

Comment: Can you please explain why finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$ algebra is not denumerable ? I know that it must be $\mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots , X_n]/I$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n].$

Comment: Because $\mathbb{C}$ is already uncountable.

Comment: But it may happen that after quotient it becomes countable

Comment: Every algebra over a field contains that field...

Comment: @user371231 In general an $A$ algebra $B$ is a ring together with a ring homomorphism $A \to B$. Any $\mathbb{C}$ algebra is therefore a ring $A$ with a map $\mathbb{C} \to A$. Unless $A=0$ this map has to be injective.